# why does declaring a static member in c++ cause the linker to link the atexit

Tags: c++, static, atexit

If I declare **sensor** as static - the linker complains about an *undefined reference to atexit.*

If I declare the sensor as non static - it does not - WHY?

//Static function in a c++ class

```
AP_Compass_Backend *AP_Compass_HMC5843::detect(Compass &compass)
{

    static AP_Compass_HMC5843 sensor(compass);
    bool result = sensor.init();

    if (result == false) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return &sensor;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Compiler is gcc 4.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I declare sensor as static - the linker complains about an undefined reference to atexit.

it looks like compiler for your platform uses `atexit` function for destruction of static objects. Normally `atexit` is used by programmer if he/she want to execute some code after application ends.

> If I declare the sensor as non static - it does not - WHY?

well, because then there are no static global objects whose destructors should be called.

It might be possible that you use some library/code which is not taking into account limitations of your platform, if it does not allow for destruction of static objects - then maybe thats because it is not possible scenario. I suggest adding empty `atexit` function as below:

```
int atexit(void (*func)()) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently in that platform the destruction of local static duration objects is done by registering an `atexit` call.

Destroying globals doesn't require anything because the destruction can be done explicitly when exiting `main` just calling all destructors in the proper order.

For local `static`s however the object may have been not constructed (if the function wasn't entered) so you need a way to register for destruction dynamically. Please rememeber that a function-level static object is constructed the first time the scope is entered (and ONLY if the scope is entered)... this is a guarantee of C++.

The dynamic destructor chain could have implemented manually (e.g. keeping a linked list), but relying on `atexit` seems another viable option.